# Get the title of a requested page using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have written the following to do AJAX requests in my app:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('ul#ui-ajax-tabs li:first').addClass('selected');

    $('#ui-ajax-tabs li a').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $("#ui-ajax-tabs li").removeClass("selected");

        $(this).parents('li').addClass("loading");

        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var link = $(this);
        console.log(url);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function (responseHtml) {
                $('div#ui-tab-content').html($(responseHtml).find('div#ui-tab-content > div#ui-ajax-html'));
                $(link).parents('li').addClass('selected');
                $("#ui-ajax-tabs li").removeClass("loading");
            },
            error: function () {
                $('div#ui-tab-content').html('<div class="message error">Sorry that page doesn\'t exist</div>');
                $(link).parents('li').addClass('selected');
                $("#ui-ajax-tabs li").removeClass("loading");
            }
        });

    });

});
```

How would I grab the title from the requested page and use it?
I've thought about something like: `var title = $(document).attr('title');` but how do I get the title from the requested page and set that as the new title? Thanks

Comment: `$(responseHtml).find('head title').text()` could work

Comment: Can jQuery's `ajax` method do cross-domain requests?

Comment: @FloydPink did you even try it before you posted it? Indeed one would expect it to work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I am new to jQuery, but I will give it a try anyways:

```
var newTitle = $(responseHtml).filter('title').text();
```

And if one of the above works, the current title could be changed by

```
document.title = newTitle;
```

Again I am a jQuery and Javascript beginner and just wanted to give it a try :) So excuse me if its stupid and wont work :)

Comment: `$("<html><head><title>Title!</title></head><body></body></html>")` gets turned into a jQuery object with a single `title` element in it so your answer actually seems to work.

Comment: +1 `filter` is the right method to use. `find` or `$('title', responseHTML)` don't work.

Comment: For security you should be using: $.parseHTML(responseHtml).filter('title').text();

Comment: Can anybody explain why neither `$(responseHtml).find('title')` nor `$("title", responseHtml)` work?

Comment: @matteo, my guess would be that `.find()` and `$('title', html)` only try to traverse the physical DOM elements, whereas `.filter()` checks the whole document, including the `head`