# Retrieving text from the <title> element from the <head> in an ajax response

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

so I'm pretty sure this question has been answered and I've figured out how to retrieve the text out a `<title>` element as stated [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/altering-content-of-title-in-head-fails), but when attempting this with ajax, FireBug responds with `undefined` with `jQuery('title', data).text()`.

```
//Ajax the next page
function grab_NextPage(){
    var NextPgElement = jQuery('.swipe_arrow.right');
    var NextPage = NextPgElement.find('a').attr('href');
    jQuery('.swipe_arrow.right').children('a').addClass('hover');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: NextPage,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(jQuery('title', data).text());
            jQuery('title').text(jQuery('title', data).text());
        }
    });
}
```

**Update**

The `data` variable from `success: function(data){}` seems to contain the `header/title` elements, but the `.text()` seems to be inaccessible although the `jQuery('title', data)` comes back with `[object Object]` (so the `object` itself seems to be accessible, the contents is not).

[image: data]

**Object `title` from `data`**

[image: datatye]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/lw0yrcmh.z1z.png))</sub>

Comment: The head and title tag is automagically stripped out by the browser when doing ajax, so it's not there.

Comment: Is there anyway to retrieve the header? with ajax?

Comment: No idea, try another datatype, like "text", and use $.parseHTML yourself ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that would matter because I've sent told the `ajax` request to return it as a `html` datatype, so parsing would occur during the request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the title of a requested page using jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599365/get-the-title-of-a-requested-page-using-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you might need this:

```
var url = 'http://google.com';
$.get("get_url.php?url="+url,function(response) {
    var title=(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(response)[1];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use `filter()` to get the `title` tag

```
success: function(data){
     console.log($(data).filter('title').text());

}
```