# jQuery .ajax() html response. Find <body>

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a .ajax call which loads a url via a post request, much like .load() would do. I am reading the responseText to get the valid HTML. I would then like to grab the ,  and my own #content id.

The title is used to replace the title of the page. The #content is the content to replace on the page, and I need the body tag for the class attribute, as their are specific classes to each page which I would like to load.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    complete: function (result) {

        var html = $('<div>' + result.responseText + '</div>'),
            title = html.filter('title:first').text(),
            b = html.find('body'),
            inner = html.find('#content').html();

        console.log(b);

        //change document title
        document.title = title;

        //add new content
        wrap.html(inner);

        //for home page
        $(window).trigger('resize');

        //fade in
        wrap.fadeIn(500, function () {

            wrap.trigger('newpage');
            $('#wrap').css('min-height', '100%');

        });

    }
});
```

Assume that wrap is defined. Please. The issue here is, I cannot retrieve body for the purposes of reading the classes. It always returns undefined. I have also tried using .filter() instead of .find(), but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: jQuery doesn't parse `html` and `body` elements, the parsed response contains html contents of the `body` element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving text from the <title> element from the <head> in an ajax response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891176/retrieving-text-from-the-title-element-from-the-head-in-an-ajax-response)

Comment: If this is the case, why am I able to retrieve the <title> tag contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every document can only one `<body>` tag, typically browsers will strip these tags out of the html.

You can test this simply in the Chrome debugger by typing in:

```
$('<div><head></head><body>Example Text</body></div>');
```

will return:

```
[<div>Example Text</div>]
```

This is documented in the [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser"s .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as  `<html>`,  `<title>`, or  `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.

Comment: I have read this. However, I am able to retrieve the contents of the <title> tag. Also, if I log the raw data returned from the .ajax() call to the console, the entire HTML doc is there, including the <head> and <body> tags.

Comment: True, but as soon as you ask JQuery to parse the HTML the browser will remove these tags. It's not the most elegant solution ever, but you might need to hardcode some string manipulation to find what you're looking for.

Comment: I actually did that as a work around already, but am still curious. If you notice in my code, I am parsing the HTML before I access the <title> tag, yet it still works ???

Comment: Yep just did a quick test in Chrome's debugger. This might be browser specific, but Chrome doesn't seem to strip the `<title>` tags. I wouldn't count on the all browsers acting the same way across the board though.

Comment: Glad you found a work around =). Somebody also posted a nice javascript regex solution here  for parsing tags out of strings if you need it still. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288277/javascript-regex-for-div-tags

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an inner element inside body. That is my strategy. I create a *phantom* div inside the body and call that in the ajax call.

Hope it works for you.