# CSS not applying to HTML page when receiving a new render in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am currently struggling on a problem of HTML response.
I have an HTML page with CSS,JS working fine, the user will do an interaction that will go to JS -> send ajax request and do some treatment within a working view. And this view give me back a rendered view with all the info updated.

The problem is that the HTML given is containing everything but looks like "raw" HTML a.k.a no CSS applied to it, (scripts are working fine)

In the head of my HTML file :

```
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sorting video: {{video.title}}</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'modelReco/cssFiles/swipeFrames.css' %}?v=00002'">
<script type="text/javascript" src='{% static "modelReco/jsScript/swipeFrames.js" %}?v=00003'></script>
  </head>
```

The view that render the HTML:

```
def sendSortVideoResponse(request,untreatedFrame,myVideo,frames,tracks,url):
    response = render(request, url, {
            'video':myVideo,
            'frames':frames,
            'tracks':tracks,
            'untreatedFrame': untreatedFrame[0],
            'countTreated': untreatedFrame[1],
            'totalFrames': len(frames),
            'progressBar': untreatedFrame[1]/len(frames)*100,
    })
   response["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" 
   response["Pragma"] = "no-cache" # HTTP 1.0.
   response["Expires"] = "0" # Proxies.
   return response
```

In settings.py :

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
SITE_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

If you F5 the page then everything works fine again.
For the user, the page he is on doesn't reload so it might be the problem but I have an other stylesheet doing a progressing bar working perfectly so I'm confused.
So it might be a bad use of static files

EDIT Network and page :

Before the interaction :[image]
After the interaction :[image]

EDIT 2 : The rendered HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sorting video: fashionShow2</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/modelReco/cssFiles/swipeFrames.css?v=00002'">
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/static/modelReco/jsScript/swipeFrames.js?v=00003'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video: fashionShow2</h1>

    <p>What can you do on this page?</p>
    <p>You've chosen to sort the video fashionShow2, this means you want to help the A.I to recognize the model by simply clicking on the models and validate your answer</p>

      <div id = 7951 class = "untreatedFrame" style="zoom:.6;-o-transform: scale(.6);-moz-transform: scale(.6)" >
        <img class = "frameImg" src="/media/fashionShow2/frames/7951.png"/>
          <a class = "frameImg" style="top: 0%; left: 65%; width: 35%; height: 100%;" onmouseover="displayValidation('rightCorner',true)" onmouseout="displayValidation('rightCorner',false)" onclick="validateFrameChoice(7951,1,true,'/modelReco/sortedTracks')">
            <div id="rightCorner" class = "validationCorner"></div>
          </a>
          <a class = "frameImg" style="top: 0%; left: 0%; width: 35%; height: 100%;" onmouseover="displayValidation('leftCorner',true),true" onmouseout="displayValidation('leftCorner',false)" onclick="validateFrameChoice(7951,-1,false,'/modelReco/sortedTracks')">
            <div id="leftCorner" class = "validationCorner"></div>
          </a>
      </div>

      <div class="w3-container">
        <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge">
          <div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-round-xlarge" style="width:73.01587301587301%">46/63</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="Cancel previous choice" onclick="cancelPreviousChoice(7951)" />

    <form action="/modelReco/">
        <input type="submit" value="Return to home" />
    </form>
    <script>
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open generated static file URL manually and show HTTP response status.

Comment: Also check HTML validity after manipulations.

Comment: I checked it on an online validator and apart from little warnings, nothing particular, I edit my HTML after interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue on this problem. If you are trying to use ajax and render a new HTML by simply replacing everything with Jquery like I did (`$("*").html(data);`).
Be careful about applying CSS on your body element because browsers ([as it is said on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259151/jquery-ajax-html-response-find-body)) usually don't care about those tags and remove it.

That's why in my retrieved ajax data, I had the body and everything but when rendered by the browser, the body tag was just disappearing.

If you need to apply CSS tags to body, just add a div tag like this and apply your css on it :

```
<body>
  <div id="body">
    .... 
  </div>
</body>
```

The only weird thing is that when you F5 the page with Django the body tag come back, so the first look was ok but when rendered without refresh no body tag was showing.

Answer (score 0):

`settings.py`

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

`urls.py` (project not app)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
...

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything ;( And Yes I putted it in the project

Comment: Try changing `{% static 'modelReco/cssFiles/swipeFrames.css' %}` to `/static/ modelReco/cssFiles/swipeFrames.css`. Apply the same to all static files that you include (css,js..)

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work either. I understand why you want to do this but my static files are well served by the network, I didn't see any errors before like '404'. The HTML has the CSS file but doesn't apply it

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache ? Sometimes browsers use old css even after changes