# How to select Title tag from HTML code using jQuery; .load

Tags: jquery, html

I am using `.load` to load the pages and change their window's title.

Page is being loaded the only issue here is that I am not able to select the title from the HTML code that is provided in the response. Here is the code

```
$('.vspageresult').load(pagetoload, function (response, status, xhr) {
  if (status != 'error') {
    // change the link in url
    window.history.pushState(null, '', pagetoload);
    // change the window's title
    document.title = response;
  }
});
```

This does everything, but you will notice that the `document.title` is set to `response` that is because of the fact that I have already tried everything, I tried using `.filter` and `.replace` but they weren't applied and a log was found in the console as

```
[<html>
  ...
</html>] does not have a method filter
```

So I left this one unmethodized. That's why I am not able to filter the title from this HTML that was provided.

Comment: In this other page they answered the same question of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599365/get-the-title-of-a-requested-page-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: I have already checked that! :) didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$(response).filter('title').text();
```

As stated before, in this post they mention it: it works to me (I tested it on Chrome, not sure about IE...)