# Youtube - SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I made a website, which opens a popup window with this **JavaScript** code:

```
document.getElementById("i_song_name").innerHTML = 
'<iframe width="100" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/FjNdYp2gXRY?autoplay=1" id="i_song_name_i"></iframe>';
```

This code adds an `iframe` tag to the `span` tag.

Then in JS, I want to get title of YouTube website with this code:

```
 document.getElementById("h3").innerHTML =
       document.getElementById("i_song_name_i")
           .contentWindow.document.head
           .getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML
           .replace(" - YouTube", "");
```

So I want to have this code:

```
<span id="i_song_name">
        <iframe width="100" 
                height="100" 
                src="https://www.youtube.com/v/FjNdYp2gXRY?autoplay=1"
                id="i_song_name_i"></iframe>
</span>
<div id="h3">Ahrix - Nova [NCS Release]</div>
```

Unfortunately, my browser (Google Chrome), still prints an error:

**SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.**

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: this is the purpose of the protection. maybe you can use youtube API for that.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because it uses jQuery and you didn't indicate that you were using it. But here is an example of using AJAX to request a pages HTML then retrieve the title from it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599365/get-the-title-of-a-requested-page-using-jquery-ajax . In other words, you could do a separate call via AJAX to get the title.

Comment: BTW, one of the answers in that article uses a regular expression to pull the title out of the response text. That is something you can do in pure javascript.

Comment: @PDKnight I am deleting my answer because it will not work as I have posted it. Upon digging deeper, I found that YouTube is blocking cross site requests. As mentioned above, you will most likely need to look into the YouTube API to get the name of the video. I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: This article may help you with a starting point on getting familiar with the YouTube API: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/05/unlocking-javascripts-potential-with.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I SOLVED IT! I used YouTube API and it works fine :)

**Edit (December 2015): Here's repaired version of the code:**

## [Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aekk40tk/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #player {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<div id="h3"></div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type YTB link here" id="input_ytb_link">
<input type="button" value="Confirm!" id="confirm_btn">
<script>
/* String.startsWith(str) */
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function'){String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){return this.indexOf(str) == 0;};}

var tag = document.createElement('script'),
    player;
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    // do nothing...
}
function setPlayer(w, h, url, eventz) {
    if (/^https?:\/\/(www\.)?youtube\.com\/.+\?(.+)?v=(.+)?$/.test(url)) {
        if (document.getElementById('player'))
            document.getElementById('player').outerHTML = '<div id="player"></div>';
        player = undefined;
        document.getElementById('h3').innerHTML = 
                'Processing, please wait a second...';
        var pos = url.indexOf('v='),
            id = url.substring(pos+2,pos+13);
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: h,
                width: w,
                videoId: id,
                events: eventz
        });
    }
}
function onPlayerReady(evt) {
        document.getElementById('h3').innerHTML = 
                evt.target.getVideoData().title;
        //evt.target.playVideo();
}
confirm_btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    setPlayer('1','1', input_ytb_link.value, {'onReady':onPlayerReady});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Thank you for your help!!**